# Puppeteer select element from innertext

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to click this button by selecting it from the inner text and not by the class.

```html
 <a class="name-link" href="/shop/...">Green Sweater</a>
```

this is what i tried

```js
await page.click('a[innerText="Green Sweater"]', elem => elem.click());
```

this is the error i get:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: a[innerText="Green Sweater"]
```

is it possible to get this selection also by using one of the words? for example, instead of Green Sweater, will it work even if i select it by searching only Green?